# How to use ALTER USER MAPPING command with arguments through db.Exec()

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, postgres-fdw, pq

Below is the code snippet

```
if _, err := db.Exec(cmd, args...); err != nil {     
   return fmt.Errorf("failed to execute command: command %s %v", v.Command, err) 
}
```

where **`cmd`** being passed is

`ALTER USER MAPPING FOR user1 SERVER myserver OPTIONS (SET password  $1 );`

and **`args`**  is

`["mypass"]`

however, I get the following error -

```
failed to execute command: command ALTER USER MAPPING FOR user1 SERVER myserver OPTIONS (SET password  $1 ); pq: syntax error at or near "$1"
```

Does anyone know where I am mistaking?

**I tried with**,

command as -

```
Insert into table1 values ($1)
```

and args as -

```
[3]
```

which works perfectly.
However, I am expecting the smilier behaviour with ALTER USER MAPPING command.

Comment: What package you are using? `sql`?

Comment: `database/sql`
and then using `pq` as a **postgres** driver.